# Changing UIView attributes via Interface Builder

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, uibutton, interface-builder

In Xcode 5 Can we change UIView attributes like background color through Interface builder. I am trying to change the background color on UIButton which inherits from UIView on interface builder but it looks like you could do that in Xcode 4.x on a custom button but in Xcode 5 that I have I do not see any options to change any attributes for the UIButton's UIView properties.

[image]

Comment: Nothing under *Attributes Inspector*?

Comment: I wanted to post an image but I cannot as this is my first question. But I see nothing under the attributes inspector under the View section at the bottom. I can change the background image etc.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Go to the view section on the right and then click on "Show". The section will scroll up.

[image]

Comment: That looks like Xcode 4. I am using Xcode 5. I will try to post an image if stack overflow allows me.

Comment: Added a link my screenshot in original question.

Comment: @nata11 I've seen your problem: Go to the view section on the right and then click on "Show". The section will scroll up.

Comment: thank you! I have been rattling this for hours. There is no indicator in Xcode which actually says that there is something invisible!